# Multiple ':not()'s within an 'on' event

Tags: jquery

In my document `on('click')` event I want the click handler to attach to everything in the document except a dynamically inserted div `('#controlElement')` and all its children. I have tried

```
$(document).on("click", "*:not(#controlElement):not(#controlElement *)", function(e) {}
```

and

```
$(document).on("click", "*:not(#controlElement, #controlElement *)", function(e) {}
```

Neither seem  to work. What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @drquicksilver correctly points out, what you are seeing is the propagation of the event up the DOM tree. If you want to stop this behaviour and not propagate when clicking on your taget element you need to invert your handler a little to call [`Event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(document).on("click", "*", 
           function(e) { 
               if($(this).is(':not(#controlElement):not(#controlElement *)')){
                   alert('clicked, on '+this.tagName); 
               }
               else{
                   e.stopPropagation();
               }
           });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Zrg6/1/

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but perhaps you're misunderstanding what you're seeing?

You indeed won't get click events on the #controlElement or any of its children, but you will still get the click events on their parents all the way up to BODY and HTML.

With some code like this you can see which elements the click event is propagating through:

```
$(document).on("click", "*:not(#controlElement):not(#controlElement *)", 
    function(e) { alert('clicked, on '+this.tagName); });
```

I did a quick example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Zrg6/